# Wikipedia-api how to scroll a page in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

I am trying to display a scrollable widget that gets text from wikipedia , but I can't get it to scroll with scrollview. Here is what I am trying:

```
    def crypto(self):

    wiki_wiki = wikipediaapi.Wikipedia (
        language='en',
        extract_format=wikipediaapi.ExtractFormat.WIKI
    )

    p_wiki = wiki_wiki.page ('page')
    return (p_wiki.text)
```

and in my .kv file:

```
    ScrollView:
        size: self.size



        Label:
            padding: root.width * .03, root.height * .03
            text: app.crypto()
            halign: "left"
            markup: True
            font_size: self.height / 15

            text_size: self.width, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            center_y: .5
            multiline: True
```

I am new to kivy, so apologies if the question is dumb and I am making a rookie mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It scrolls now I made a ScrollableLabel:

```
ScrollableLabel:

            Label:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width, None
                text: app.cyber()
```

and in main.py:

```
class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('')
```